# program won't run again

Tags: python, input

program won't run again upon y input, please help, n works just fine have no idea why, is it my while loop?, having a lot of trouble with this for about 2 hours any help is appreciated. also do I need to use a while True: ?????

```
import random

def main():

        print("This program will play a game with you! You'll get 3 chances to guess correctly at a number chosen at random by the computer betwen 1 and 10")
        yn = input("Would you like to play the game?(Y/N): ")
        if yn.upper() != 'Y':
            print("Ok have a nice day!")

        the_number = random.randint(1, 10)
        guess = int(input("Take a guess: "))
        tries = 1

        # guessing loop
        while guess != the_number:
            if guess > the_number:
                print("Got to go lower bud")
            else:
                print("Got to go higher bud")

            guess = int(input("Take a guess: "))
            tries += 1
            if tries == 3:
                print ("You failed to guess in time, the number was", the_number)
                break
            if guess == the_number:
                print("You guessed it! The number was", the_number)
                print("And it only took you", tries, "tries!")

        yn = input("Would you like to play the game?(Y/N): ")
        if yn.upper() != 'Y':
            print("Ok have a nice day!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Comment: It's not inside a loop. I wouldn't expect it to run again. You need to either call `main` again, or wrap it in another loop.

Answer (score 0):

As @Carcigenicate said you will want to put it in a loop/function or call main again

```
import random

def main():
    print("This program will play a game with you! You'll get 3 chances to guess correctly at a number chosen at random by the computer betwen 1 and 10")    
    yn = input("Would you like to play the game?(Y/N): ")
    while yn.upper() == 'Y':
        the_number = random.randint(1, 10)
        guess = int(input("Take a guess: "))
        tries = 1

        # guessing loop
        while guess != the_number:
            if guess > the_number:
                print("Got to go lower bud")
            else:
                print("Got to go higher bud")

            guess = int(input("Take a guess: "))
            tries += 1
            if tries == 3:
                print ("You failed to guess in time, the number was", the_number)
                break
            if guess == the_number:
                print("You guessed it! The number was", the_number)
                print("And it only took you", tries, "tries!")
        yn = input("Would you like to play the game?(Y/N): ")
    print("Ok have a nice day!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```